# Assigning 2d arrays C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have got struct and function , and i want to assign one array poiner to pointer in my struct:

```
struct
{
int array[3][2]

}some_struct;

void example(some_struct* st, int array[3][2])
{

     //st->array=array 
     //st->array[0]=array[0],st->array[1]=array[1],st->array[2]=array[2]

  // how to do that ??

}
```

Comment: do you want that `st->array` will point to the `array` or do you want to copy the values from `array` to `st->array` ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately arrays by themselves cannot be assigned.

Since both arrays have the same dimensions and sizes (do they?) the easiest is to use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(st->array, array, sizeof st->array);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be much simpler if you used one-dimensional tables. Here's the example. Note the difference between holding a pointer and a fixed-size table!

```
typedef struct
{
   int* array;
} some_struct;

void example (some_struct* st, int* array)
{
    st->array = array;
}
```

If you still want to use 2-dimensional ones, you really need to assign every table of the 2nd level, as they don't have to be linear in memory.

EDIT: If the 2-dimensional arrays are indeed always linear in memory in C, the above statement should work if you give it 2-dimensional array as a parameter to `example` function.

Comment: `as they don't have to be linear in memory`. in C 2 dimensional array are always linear in memory.

Comment: Oh, I'll change my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to copy the values as I see it, I would do it like that:

```
struct
{
int array[3][2]

}some_struct;

void example(some_struct* st, int *array, int dim)
{
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i<dim; i++)
        st->array[i]=array[i];
}

//Use:
some_struct try_st;
array[3][2] orig_st;
//put your data in the array

example(try_st, orig_st, 3*2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If array is the first member in your struct-declaration you can simple copy it like:

```
struct
{
int array[3][2]

}some_struct;

void example(some_struct* st, int array[3][2])
{
  *st = *(some_struct*)array;
}
```

All other struct-members are destroyed here, it make only sense if your struct contains only the array member.